# Null-conditional operator and string interpolation in C# 6

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-6.0

Do the [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) and [interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) syntax resolve to just [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)?

The null-conditional operator (`?.`), which allows code clean-up through reducing "excessive" `null` checking, and interpolated strings (`("\{X}, \{Y}")`), which brings the arguments and format into one, are new features in C# 6.

Do these get compiled to their undesirable counterparts (i.e. the ugly code we sought to avoid)?

I apologize for the naïve question, I don't have the best understanding of languages in general, but I'm curious if it would be possible to run these features on, say, C# 5.

I know this is the case with Java in some instances, is it true as well with these examples?

Comment: Elvis operator is something else. It's actually a **Null coalescing operator**, which picks the first non-null value. `?.` is trying to traverse the object down the property chain, it returns non-null only if the whole chain evaluation succeeded. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator UPDATE - found a name for `?.`, it's called [Safe Navigation Operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator.aspx).

Comment: C# already has the [`??` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).  Is that not the same thing?

Comment: [Apparently not](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Connect-event-2014/116). @RyanBemrose. Maybe it is but is changed`??`

Comment: As an update to future readers, the "Elvis operator" has been officially named the "null-conditional operator" in C# 6.0

Comment: I like Elvis operator better :)

Comment: Who cares what your code is compiled into?  The only considerations you should have are 1) what is the most concise and clear way I can express an algorithm and 2) how fast and reliable is the result of the compilation.  You realize that GOTO is used extensively in IL, right?  ***GOTO***.  Imagine all your clean, elegant code reduced to a bunch of lousy GOTO statements.  Now go shower.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There isn't a general rule, it differs. Some features are simply syntactic sugar, some add capabilities that weren't possible before, and some are a combination of both.

### Syntactic Sugar

- String interpolation - This:

  ```
  string result = $"{bar}";
  ```

  Instead of:

  ```
  string result = string.Format("{0}", bar);
  ```
- Null-propagating operator (`?.`) - This:

  ```
  var result = Foo()?.Length
  ```

  Instead of:

  ```
  var temp = Foo();
  var result = (temp != null) ? temp.Length : null;
  ```

### New Capabilities

- String interpolation - Also adds support for `IFormattable` using `FormattedString` so this is possible:

  ```
  IFormattable result =  $"{bar}"
  ```
- Await in catch/finally - It's now possible to use `await` in `catch` and `finally` blocks:

  ```
  try
  {
  }
  catch
  {
      await Task.Delay(1000);
  }
  ```

There are of course more features in both categories, like exception filters and expression-bodied members.

Comment: So maybe the general rule for programmers is to either have a thorough understanding of the behaviors of these features or default to the version they're implemented.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils that's reasonable.

Comment: So, I apparently have been writing C# from a very basic level. Why is `?.` needed if we already have `??` as suggested in the comments? Are they redundant or changed?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils those are different operators with different purpose. `??` is the null coalescing operator. `?.` is the null conditional operator (or safe navigation operator)

Comment: 1. `var result = GetString() ?? string.Empty;`
2. `var result = GetString()?.Length`

Comment: @PauloMorgado of course. That's why it was already available in IL.

Answer (score 11):

Like most of the new features in C#6.0, the null-conditional operator is just shorthand (syntactic sugar, if you want to call it) for a pattern of getting the value of a member if the instance the variable being used is not null.

Given a `s` of type `string`, this:

```
int? l = s?.Length;
```

is translated into:

```
int? l = s == null ? null : s.Length;
```

And it can be combined with the **null coalescing operator** (`??`):

```
int l = s?.Length ?? 0;
```

String interpolation also started as shorthand for `string.Format` but evolved to a pattern that can either produce a `string` or an `IFormatble`. Please, refer to the [current spec](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/570292) for more information.

And, by the way, **roslyn** is the code name for the compiler platform, not the languages or their features.

Comment: Yes, roslyn is the name for the compiler platform. I asked about the code these features were compiled to, someone edited the post and added the tag, seemed appropriate/reasonable to me. A distinction/clarification between your claims and the accepted answer would be great. Thanks for the link; I currently don't have the time to do spec reading hence asking here, but will dive in soon.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, the link I posted is for the spec of the string interpolation - fairly short. As for the "Elvis" operator, unless you want to spend a month or two going through all the discussions, it's pretty much what I posted.

Answer (score 2):

The Elvis operator is very useful when calling the RaisePropertyChanged event.

In the past you would write

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(X));
}
```

But there was a potential multi threading issue if PropertyChanged was set to null before it was invoked.  Instead you can write:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(X));
```

Which completely avoids the multi threading issue - so it's not quite Syntax sugar.

Comment: minor note: "in the past" `nameof()` did not exist. it entered the language together with the null-conditional operator. also, the race condition was resolved by extracting both references to a local variable. so you "only" save a few keystrokes (which is not necessarily something to be scoffed at)

Comment: even smaller note: Null-propagating operator is the `?.` which you are referring to above as the Elvis operator which is the `?:` which does indeed look like Elvis.

Comment: No, it does *not* avoid multi threading issues, they are just shifted slightly. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35786442/1671066.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann, MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx says otherwise.