# Can't set nullable int to LINQ query's return value?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to retrieve an Id from a table based on certain criteria.  If the criteria isn't met, I just want to return the default value (in this case, I'm assuming null).  Here's my code:

```
int? circuitTypeId = cimsContext.CircuitTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Name == circuitType).Id;
```

I am assuming that if there isn't a match between `ct.Name` and `circuitType` that the value returned is `null`.  However, when running my program, I get an error on this line saying "Null reference exception".  I know that the record isn't there, but shouldn't I be able to assign the `null` returned by the query to my `nullable int` variable?

Comment: No, at the moment you'll need to explicitly check for null before dereferencing Id. Or you can wait for [Roslyn's Elvis](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27493541/314291) operator `?.` :)

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` is worthless in this situation because you're trying to access `Id` from potentially `null`. `First` would at least throw a better exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first check for `null` before assigning the `circuitTypeId` variable:

```
int? circuitTypeId;

var circuitType = cimsContext.CircuitTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Name == circuitType);
if(circuitType != null)
{
    circuitTypeId = circuitType.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your assumption is wrong, as per your query:-

```
int? circuitTypeId = cimsContext.CircuitTypes
                                .FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Name == circuitType).Id;
```

This will return `int`, when match is found but it will throw a `Null Reference Exception` when no name matches with that of `circuitType`. you should do this:-

```
var circuitTypeObj = cimsContext.CircuitTypes
                                .FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Name == circuitType);
int? circuitTypeId = circuitTypeObj == null ? (int?)null : circuitTypeObj.Id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
int? circuitTypeId = cimsContext.CircuitTypes.Where(ct => ct.Name == circuitType).Select(p => p.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer ;-) short and clean without unnecessary `if`s.

Comment: Nope.  This will return a `0` instead of a `null`.

Answer (score 3):

In C# version 6 you can simply add a `?` before `id` to prevent the properties of null objects from being referenced.

```
int? circuitTypeId = cimsContext.CircuitTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Name == circuitType)?.Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `.Id` is probably trying to reference a null CirctuitType.

```
var circuitType = cimsContext.CircuitTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Name == circuitType);
int? circuitTypeId = circuitType.Id; // if circuitType is null, a null reference exception is thrown
```

Instead, you'll need to test the reference for null:

```
var circuitType = cimsContext.CircuitTypes.FirstOrDefault(ct => ct.Name == circuitType);
int? circuitTypeId = (circuitType == null ? (int?)null : circuitType.Id);
```