# C# How to check if Textbox doesn't contains string

Tags: c#, string, textbox, contains

i need to check if my textbox doesn't contain specific string "Fold". I used to do this like this

```
if (textbox.Text.Contains("Fold"){}
else { do stuff }
```

but now i need some alternative of this.

Comment: Why do you have an alternative? This is the simplest way.

Comment: im checking 4-5 things at a time and i will have to do a lot of if statements also there's quite some code if the statement is true and i will have to either make it into new method or copy and paste it ..

Comment: What is the problem with doing it this way? What else have you tried?

Comment: if (!textbox.Text.Contains("Fold"){  do stuff }

Comment: Roslyn rules! - textbox.Text?.Contains("Fold")

Comment: thanks adv12 that's what i needed and btw it seems simpler than mine

Comment: Please explain your problem with full disclosure of your various if statement otherwise you cannot get correct answers

Comment: @kopelence So are you asking how to use the || operator?

Comment: @Daniil i dont understand do you mean i should check if it the textbox.text!=null and than do things :?

Comment: already got an answer if (!textbox.Text.Contains("Fold"){ do stuff }

Comment: @kopelence maybe you find this usefully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493541/elvis-operator-and-string-formatter-in-c-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the boolean:

```
if (!textBox.Text.Contains("Fold")) { ... }
```

Or you can compare with `false` as **@adv12** said:

```
if (textBox.Text.Contains("Fold") == false) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to adv12 i found this piece of code to work perfectly

```
if (textBox.Text.Contains("Fold")==false)
```

or

```
if (!textBox.Text.Contains("Fold"))
```

Comment: This should have been marked `Answer` -You posted first.

Answer (score 0):

Please use !textbox.Text.Contains("Fold") the exclamation mark means 'not'.

Answer (score 0):

You can get in a real time using TextChanged event of the TextBox. Much better way before users submits their result.

Answer (score 0):

Use if (!textbox.Text.Equals("Fold") = true) {...}