# c# ?. conditional operator

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

I have a condition

```
if (driver?.VistrackId == 555)
```

it equivalent (in IL code, not C# code):

```
if (driver != null && driver.VistrackId == 555)
```

right?

Comment: `if (driver?.VistrackId == 555)` is this compiling ?

Comment: you can compare the IL in LINQPad

Comment: `if((driver == null ? null : driver.VistrackId) == 555)`

Comment: This is not `IL`, this is still `C#`, but without syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly

> It's better Since this notation is thread safe

See [*Null-conditional Operators* on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

Comment: I think the thread-safety in the article is directed towards handling delegates, not necessarily towards handling variables. It depends on the situation if it is actually thread-safe. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35786442/9239792) for a discussion on the thread-safety of the operator.

Comment: @RMH but as I understand this operation is kind of atomic, and you can't set `null` your variable during null propagation is processed, even you set object to `null` you still be referencing initial object

Comment: my apologies, I misinterpreted your meaning (and the doc's) of 'thread safe' here. I agree that the variable cannot become null during its null-check exactly as you stated. In that sense it is a 'thread-safe null-check'. However, this does not hold for the called property / method (`VistrackId` in the post's case).

Answer (score 2):

That's correct. The "?" checks for null, and if it's not null, the "." continues the interrogation of the object

Answer (score 1):

This code generates the following IL

```
var driver = new {VistrackId = 1};

if (driver?.VistrackId == 555)
{
    Console.WriteLine("?. operator");
}
```

IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  newobj      <>f__AnonymousType0<System.Int32>..ctor
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // driver
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     // driver
IL_0009:  brtrue.s    IL_000E
IL_000B:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000C:  br.s        IL_001B
IL_000E:  ldloc.0     // driver
IL_000F:  call        <>f__AnonymousType0<System.Int32>.get_VistrackId
IL_0014:  ldc.i4      2B 02 00 00 
IL_0019:  ceq         
IL_001B:  stloc.1     
IL_001C:  ldloc.1     
IL_001D:  brfalse.s   IL_002C
IL_001F:  nop         
IL_0020:  ldstr       "?. operator"
IL_0025:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_002A:  nop         
IL_002B:  nop         
IL_002C:  ret
```

Code with `== null`

```
var driver = new {VistrackId = 1};


if (driver != null && driver.VistrackId == 555)
{
    Console.WriteLine("== null");
}
```

IL

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  newobj      <>f__AnonymousType0<System.Int32>..ctor
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // driver
IL_0008:  ldloc.0     // driver
IL_0009:  brfalse.s   IL_001A
IL_000B:  ldloc.0     // driver
IL_000C:  callvirt    <>f__AnonymousType0<System.Int32>.get_VistrackId
IL_0011:  ldc.i4      2B 02 00 00 
IL_0016:  ceq         
IL_0018:  br.s        IL_001B
IL_001A:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_001B:  stloc.1     
IL_001C:  ldloc.1     
IL_001D:  brfalse.s   IL_002C
IL_001F:  nop         
IL_0020:  ldstr       "== null"
IL_0025:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_002A:  nop         
IL_002B:  nop         
IL_002C:  ret
```

They are slightly different