# ?. Invalid Expression Term

Tags: c#

I am follow a tutorial and getting an error. Can rewrite statement:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

Code:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: What is exception that you are getting?

Comment: why there is `?` i your code?

Comment: What C# compiler version you use?

Comment: @david This is a null propagation operator. It just checks if `PropertyChanged` is null. But it will only work with c# 6.0 or higher, i think.

Comment: Change to: `if PropertyChanged != null PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, ...)`

Answer (score 2):

If you are in working in a previous version to C# 6, you can do this

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if(PropertyChanged != null)
       PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**Further reading**

[?. and ?[] null-conditional Operators (C# and Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

> Tests the value of the left-hand operand for null before performing a
>   member access (?.) or index (?[]) operation; returns null if the
>   left-hand operand evaluates to null.

and

> The null-conditional operators are short-circuiting. If one operation
>   in a chain of conditional member access and index operation returns
>   null, then the rest of the chain’s execution stop

**Update from Jeff's comment**

> The implementation you give above is one of the foremost use cases for
>   ?. for thread safety - you should be saving the event field to a local
>   variable before checking if it’s null and invoking – Jeff 1

and he is 100 percent correct

Ideally you should do this

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var changedEvent = PropertyChanged;
    if(changedEvent != null)
       changedEvent.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

For more information on this here is a reference to a relevant question provided by *pinkfloydx33*

[Is C# 6 ?. (Elvis op) thread safe? If so, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784874/is-c-sharp-6-elvis-op-thread-safe-if-so-how#35786442)

Comment: The implementation you give above is one of the foremost use cases for ?. for thread safety  - you should be saving the event field to a local variable before checking if it’s null and invoking

Comment: Null conditional already uses a temporary variable when invoking event handlers. Though, see the second highest answer and also Eric's comments about it all here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35786442/491907

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 agreed and very correct, and its worth linking that answer as well for clarity into the update. thanks